# How to Highlight smallest value from 4 columns? mysql + PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pricing ORDER BY Product ASC LIMIT 5000");
```

and the PHP to follow

```
$counter = 0;
$btncounter = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$counter=$counter+1;
$btncounter=$btncounter+1;
print "<tr>\n";
print "<td>".$row['Product']."</td>\n";
print "<td>".$row['Price1']."</td>\n";
print "<td>".$row['Price2']."</td>\n";
print "<td>".$row['Price3']."</td>\n";
print "<td>".$row['Price4']."</td></tr>\n";
```

I want to show the lowest price in red/bold/or underline, I'm trying to figure out how to use the Least() function, something along the lines of:
    LEAST(price1, price2, price3, price4)

```
if($row['Price1'] == LEAST(price1, price2, price3, price4)
{print "<td>Price 1 in Red</td>\n";}
```

or something along that route?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Jan - I've tried to utilise your answer:
but my results are all showing as red,
I have the mysql query the same as yours.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$counter=$counter+1;
$btncounter=$btncounter+1;
print "<tr>\n";
print "<td>".$row['ID']."</td>\n";
print "<td>".$row['Product']."</td>\n";
if ($result['price1'] == $result['smallest_price']) { print "<td><span style='color:red'>".$row['price1']."</span></td>\n"; } else {print "<td>".$row['price1']."</td>\n";}
if ($result['price2'] == $result['smallest_price']) { print "<td><span style='color:red'>".$row['price2']."</span></td>\n"; } else {print "<td>".$row['price2']."</td>\n";}
if ($result['price3'] == $result['smallest_price']) { print "<td><span style='color:red'>".$row['price3']."</span></td>\n"; } else {print "<td>".$row['price3']."</td>\n";}
if ($result['price4'] == $result['smallest_price']) { print "<td><span style='color:red'>".$row['price4']."</span></td>\n"; } else {print "<td>".$row['price4']."</td>\n";}
print "<td>".$row['Last_updated']."</td>\n";
```

}

Would I be right in adding the else?

Update 10th October 2013 - Got it working (kind of)...

used:
    if ($row['Price1'] == $row['smallest_price']) { print "".$row['Price1']."\n"; } else { print "".$row['Price1']."\n";}

***but it only works when there's values in for all FOUR prices - what if a value isn't there?***

Answer (score 3):

You should use the Mysql least function in your query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, LEAST(price1, price2, price3, price4) AS smallest_price FROM pricing ORDER BY Product ASC LIMIT 5000");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if ($result['price1'] == $result['smallest_price']) {
         // print price 1 in red
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jan, I've tried to implement your answer, but my results are all showing as red, - I've commented again.,

Comment: can you modify your price columns to not null and with default value = 0.00? for example like this: 
`ALTER TABLE  pricing CHANGE  price1 price1 DECIMAL( 12, 2 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0.00'`

Comment: @CraigDearden did it work for you now? it would be nice if you accepted my answer then

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort` function to sort them from `low to high`.

```
$values = sort(array($row['Price1'], $row['Price2'], $row['Price3'], $row['Price4'], SORT_NUMERIC));

echo $values[0]; //lowest price
```

Answer (score 0):

Use http://php.net/min ?

```
$counter = 0;
$btncounter = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$counter=$counter+1;
$btncounter=$btncounter+1;
print "<tr>\n";
print "<td>".$row['Product']."</td>\n";
$prices = array($row['Price1'],$row['Price2'],$row['Price3'],$row['Price4']);
$minimum_price = min($prices)
foreach ( $prices as $price) {
   $price_text = $price;
   if ($price == $minimum_price) {
      $price_text = "<span style='color:red'>$price_text</span>";
   }
   print "<td>".$price_text."</td>\n";
}
```